# (Build Failed) Add-Migration Initial

Tags: c#, .net

I am following a course on .NET

I need to write 'Add-Migration Initial' in the Package Manager Console under the PieController.cs file.

When I do, I get a "build failed" message with no error list.

What is the problem that cause the build failed?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using BethanysPieShop.Models;
using BethanysPieShop.ViewModels;


namespace BethanysPieShop.Controllers
{
    public class PieController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IPieRepository _pieRepository;
        private readonly ICategoryRepository _categoryRepository;

        public PieController(IPieRepository pieRepository, ICategoryRepository categoryRepository)
        {
            _pieRepository = pieRepository;
            _categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
        }

        public ViewResult List()
        {
            PiesListViewModel piesListViewModel = new PiesListViewModel();
            piesListViewModel.Pies = _pieRepository.Pies;

            piesListViewModel.CurrentCategory = "Cheese cakes";

            return View(piesListViewModel);
        }

    }
}
```

Course Results Below(1) ;

[image]

Comment: - My project is named WebApplication5

Answer (score 12):

Here some actions you can do:

- close and open again your Visual Studio, clean and build again your project and run add-migration again
- check if you have build errors
- check if you have foreign keys errors or errors on your db schema

For sure something or some error can't get your migration ready.

Comment: close and open vscode solved for me, after installing `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.1.5`

Answer (score 1):

In my case same problem was caused of my main project has ref to another one with different version of EFCore. So I had to delete project reference before I was able to manage migrations. Going to same EF version in all linked projects should be solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, this was caused by other errors, and after the error was corrected, it worked. In the _ViewStart.cshtml, I had to Change Layout = _Layout to  Layout = "_Layout".

In other cases may be due to other errors.